# Affix a Div while scrolling

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, css, html

I have two sections in an LWC and the section 1 contains lot of data hence that section scrolls. The section 2 is a fixed size div which has inner scrolling. Now I need the div on the right side(the smaller div with fixed height) to be affixed even when we scroll for data. Image 1 shows the div's
[image]

In the below image is when I scroll to the bottom. The smaller div's position is fixed. I have tried to use various "position" styles but none of them helped. I want the smaller div to be affixed so that the user wont be scrolling back to the top to access the data.
[image]

The playground url is : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/D9EG6u9FA/5/edit .

Comment: you want the right div to be fixed when scrolling?

Comment: Yes. That’s correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by adding following css to the top div

```
.fixed{
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
}
```

here is a playground
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/D9EG6u9FA/7/edit